# Throws an missing \item error when I try to use a nested enumerate to have an alphabetical list

Tags: enumitem

I am trying to use a nested enumerate block to have an alphabetical list and it throws an error (! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item) when the nested block isn't in a quote block. I want to remove the quote block so the lists aren't indented as far. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Do not alter this block of commands.  If you're proficient at LaTeX, you may include additional packages, create macros, etc. immediately below this block of commands, but make sure to NOT alter the header, margin, and comment settings here. 
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts, enumitem, fancyhdr, color, comment, graphicx, environ}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \thispagestyle{fancy}% First page
  \pagestyle{empty}% Other pages
}
\setlength{\headheight}{65pt}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{sol}
    {\emph{Solution:}
    }
    {
    \qed
    }
\specialcomment{com}{ \color{blue} \textbf{Comment:} }{\color{black}} %for instructor comments while grading
\NewEnviron{probscore}{\marginpar{ \color{blue} \tiny Problem Score: \BODY \color{black} }}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Fill in the appropriate information below
\lhead{Student Name}  %replace with your name
\rhead{XYZ} %replace XYZ with the homework course number, semester (e.g. ``Spring 2019"), and assignment number.
 \chead{\textbf{\Large Homework 0}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
%Do not alter this block.
\begin{document}

%BLOCK 1
%Copy the following block of text for each problem in the assignment.
\textbf{Exercise 0.1:} Sigma notation review: Write the sum in expanded form:
\begin{quote}
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\sum_{i=1}^5\sqrt{i}=\boxed{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{5}}$
\item $\sum_{i=1}^ni^10=\boxed{1^10+2^10+3^10+\cdots+n^10}$
\item $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i=\boxed{(-1)^0+(-1)^1+(-1)^2+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}}$
\item $\sum_{j=0}^{n+3}j^2=\boxed{0^2+1^2+2^2+\cdots+j^2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{quote}

%BLOCK 2
%Copy the following block of text for each problem in the assignment.
\textbf{Exercise 0.2:} Sigma notation review: Write the sum in sigma notation:

\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 +\cdots+ 10=\boxed{\sum_{i=1}^{10}i}$
\item $ 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 +\cdots+2n=\boxed{\sum_{i=1}^{n}2i}$
\item $1 +x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n=\boxed{\sum_{i=0}^nx^i}$
\item $1 + 2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots+(n-1)x^n=\boxed{\sum_{i=2}^n(n-1)x^n}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


%BLOCK 3
%Copy the following block of text for each problem in the assignment.
\textbf{Exercise 0.3:} Factorial review: What is the factorial function? What notation is used for this function?
\\ A factorial function uses the notation $``x!"$ and is equivalent to $\prod_{i=0}^{x-1}(x-i)$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The combination `\begin{quote}
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}` is wrong. You can set the enumerate numbering styles either with `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}`, or more conveniently with the `enumitem` package. You should not wrap an enumerate environment in a `quote` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Thinks, this is what you are looking for

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts, enumitem, fancyhdr, color, comment, graphicx, environ}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \thispagestyle{fancy}% First page
  \pagestyle{empty}% Other pages
}
\setlength{\headheight}{65pt}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{sol}
    {\emph{Solution:}
    }
    {
    \qed
    }
\specialcomment{com}{ \color{blue} \textbf{Comment:} }{\color{black}} %for instructor comments while grading
\NewEnviron{probscore}{\marginpar{ \color{blue} \tiny Problem Score: \BODY \color{black} }}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Fill in the appropriate information below
\lhead{Student Name}  %replace with your name
\rhead{XYZ} %replace XYZ with the homework course number, semester (e.g. ``Spring 2019"), and assignment number.
 \chead{\textbf{\Large Homework 0}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setenumerate{itemsep=3pt,topsep=3pt,leftmargin=1in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
%Do not alter this block.
\begin{document}

%BLOCK 1
%Copy the following block of text for each problem in the assignment.
\textbf{Exercise 0.1:} Sigma notation review: Write the sum in expanded form:
%\begin{quote}
%\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $\sum_{i=1}^5\sqrt{i}=\boxed{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{5}}$
\item $\sum_{i=1}^ni^10=\boxed{1^10+2^10+3^10+\cdots+n^10}$
\item $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i=\boxed{(-1)^0+(-1)^1+(-1)^2+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}}$
\item $\sum_{j=0}^{n+3}j^2=\boxed{0^2+1^2+2^2+\cdots+j^2}$
\end{enumerate}
%\end{enumerate}
%\end{quote}

%BLOCK 2
%Copy the following block of text for each problem in the assignment.
\textbf{Exercise 0.2:} Sigma notation review: Write the sum in sigma notation:

%\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 +\cdots+ 10=\boxed{\sum_{i=1}^{10}i}$
\item $ 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 +\cdots+2n=\boxed{\sum_{i=1}^{n}2i}$
\item $1 +x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n=\boxed{\sum_{i=0}^nx^i}$
\item $1 + 2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots+(n-1)x^n=\boxed{\sum_{i=2}^n(n-1)x^n}$
\end{enumerate}
%\end{enumerate}


%BLOCK 3
%Copy the following block of text for each problem in the assignment.
\textbf{Exercise 0.3:} Factorial review: What is the factorial function? What notation is used for this function?
\\ A factorial function uses the notation $``x!"$ and is equivalent to $\prod_{i=0}^{x-1}(x-i)$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And if you're going to be doing this every time, you can use `enumitem` to make that the default.